# The "ssl" parameter requires ngx_http_ssl_module

Tags: nginx, ssl, configuration

I just built nginx with pagespeed module and i want to enable the ssl, but everytime enable the ssl server tag,and restart the nginx , i got this error

```
2018/04/30 04:53:45 [emerg] 1808#0: the "ssl" parameter requires ngx_http_ssl_module in /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:184
```

here is my config file.

```
user  root root;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    client_body_temp_path  "/usr/local/nginx/client_body_temp" 1 2;
    proxy_temp_path "/usr/local/nginx/proxy_temp" 1 2;
    fastcgi_temp_path "/usr/local/nginx/fastcgi_temp" 1 2;
    scgi_temp_path "/usr/local/nginx/scgi_temp" 1 2;
    uwsgi_temp_path "/usr/local/nginx/uwsgi_temp" 1 2;

    fastcgi_cache_path /usr/local/nginx/fastcgi_cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=phpcache:100m inactive=60m;
    fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";



    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip on;


    add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    add_header Cache-Control "s-maxage=691200";
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
    server {
        listen       80;
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
        server_name  mysite.com;
       # root         html;
         root        /var/www/snu/htdocs/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;


        pagespeed on;
        pagespeed FileCachePath "/var/cache/ngx_pagespeed/";
        pagespeed RewriteLevel OptimizeForBandwidth;

        location ~ "\.pagespeed\.([a-z]\.)?[a-z]{2}\.[^.]{10}\.[^.]+" {
            add_header "" "";
        }

        location ~ "^/pagespeed_static/" { }
        location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_beacon$" { }

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        #location / {
        #    root   html;
        #   index  index.html index.htm;
        #}

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}



    location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpeg|jpg|png|woff|ttf|otf|svg|woff2|eot)$ {
       expires 1d;
       access_log off;
       add_header Pragma public;
       add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=86400";
       add_header X-Asset "yes";
   }



        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #

     #  location ~ \.php$ {
     #       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
     #   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
     #       fastcgi_index index.php;
     #       include fastcgi_params;
     #     }


    #location ~ \.php$ {
      #fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
      #fastcgi_index  index.php;
      #fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      #include fastcgi_params;
    #}

       location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_cache phpcache;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 60m;
       }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }





    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;

    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

  server {
    listen       443 ssl ;

    listen [::]:443 ipv6only=on;

    server_name  mysite.com;

   ssl_certificate mysite.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  mysite.com.key;

    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;


     root        /var/www/snu/htdocs/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;


    pagespeed on;
    pagespeed FileCachePath "/var/cache/ngx_pagespeed/";
    pagespeed RewriteLevel OptimizeForBandwidth;

    location ~ "\.pagespeed\.([a-z]\.)?[a-z]{2}\.[^.]{10}\.[^.]+" {
        add_header "" "";
    }

    location ~ "^/pagespeed_static/" { }
    location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_beacon$" { }


    location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpeg|jpg|png|woff|ttf|otf|svg|woff2|eot)$ {
       expires 1d;
       access_log off;
       add_header Pragma public;
     add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=86400";
       add_header X-Asset "yes";
      }

     location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_cache phpcache;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 60m;
       }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}

    }

}
```

also i have installed open ssl, so when i run this `nginx -V` i got this

```
   nginx version: nginx/1.10.3
built with OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/nginx-2tpxf                                                                                                 
c/nginx-1.10.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdat                                                                                                 
e-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/

access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.                                                                                                 
lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/

fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 **--with-http_ssl_module** --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module

with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module 

with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic 

--with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic 

--with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic 

--with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-2tpxfc/ng                                                                                                 inx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-2tpxf                                                                                                 c/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-dynamic-module=/build/n                                                                                                 ginx-2tpxfc/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-dynamic-module=/build/n                                                                                                 ginx-2tpxfc/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-dynamic-module                                                                                                 =/build/nginx-2tpxfc/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_m                                                                                                 odule
```

which is showing this line `--with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module`

please suggest what i am doing wrong?

Comment: You may have a packaged version of nginx installed in addition to the one you compiled from source and your startup script calls a different binary than the one in your default path that you see when you run with `nginx-v`

Comment: ok , i got it, do you know how can i configure multiple modules with nginx like pagespeed, http, 

for eg: `./configure --with-pagespeed, --with http_ssl_module`